# Cannot convert value of type 'Meme!' to expected argument type '@noescape (Meme) throws -> Bool'

Tags: arrays, swift, indexof

Here is the code:

```
    @IBAction func deleteMeme(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
       if let foundIndex = MemeRepository.sharedInstance.memes.indexOf(selectedMeme) {     
        //remove the item at the found index
        MemeRepository.sharedInstance.memes.removeAtIndex(foundIndex)
        navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

The error happens at the `.indexOf` method at `(selectedMeme)`.

Cannot convert value of type `Meme!` to expected argument type `@noescape (Meme) throws -> Bool`

Meme! is a struct for my app. How do I work through this?

```
struct Meme {

var topText : String!
var bottomText: String!
var image: UIImage!
var memedImage: UIImage!

init(topText: String, bottomText: String, image: UIImage, memedImage: UIImage) {
    self.topText = topText
    self.bottomText = bottomText
    self.image = image
    self.memedImage = memedImage
```

Answer (score 44):

The error message is misleading. What you actually need is to provide the compiler a way to compare two `Meme` instances and decide upon which criteria those instances are equal.

Let's say you want two instances having the same `name` property to be treated as equal.

We make the struct conform to `Equatable` and we also create an `==` operator that compares two structs by their name property:

```
struct Meme:Equatable {
    var name:String!
}

func ==(lhs: Meme, rhs: Meme) -> Bool {
    return lhs.name == rhs.name
}
```

Now we can use `indexOf` with a Meme instance:

```
let doge = Meme(name: "doge")

let lolcat = Meme(name: "lolcat")

let memes = [lolcat, doge]

if let dogeIndex = memes.indexOf(doge) {
    print(dogeIndex)  // 1
}
```

If you wanted to compare two instances not by their `name` property but by their uniqueness, then you would have to make the struct conform to `Hashable` and use a unique `hashValue` property returning an Int:

```
struct Meme:Hashable {
    var name:String!
    var hashValue: Int {
        return self.name.hashValue
    }
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

func ==(lhs: Meme, rhs: Meme) -> Bool {
    return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
}

let doge = Meme(name: "doge")

let lolcat = Meme(name: "lolcat")

let memes = [lolcat, doge]

if let dogeIndex = memes.indexOf(doge) {
    print(dogeIndex)  // 1
}
```

In this example the `hashValue` is made from `self.name`, so two different instances of Meme with a same name property will be considered equal. If you don't want that, use another source for the hash value.

*Note: in Swift 3, `indexOf` has become `index(of:)`, so for this example we would change `memes.indexOf(doge)` to `memes.index(of: doge)`.*

Answer (score 5):

If you want to put the comparison inside the indexOf method itself, do it like this:

```
if let foundIndex = MemeRepository.sharedInstance.memes.indexOf({
  UIImagePNGRepresentation($0.memedImage) == UIImagePNGRepresentation(selectedMeme.memedImage)})
```

Probably not the best way to compare images. If you know the images are the same object, you can use:

```
.indexOf({$0.memedImage == selectedMeme.memedImage})
```

but if you want to compare them pixel by pixel or compare the same image scaled to different sizes, that is a little more complicated.

Comment: Thank you all for your input and help. I appreciate the time and effort. Here's my project if you want to check it out: https://github.com/pbellot77/MemeMe.git