# Swift 2.1: Removing duplicates from an array of structs?

Tags: macos, duplicates, swift2

I have an array of structs (the struct has nothing in it by strings so I guess I could have used an array of arrays of strings but I thought I might want to add some non-string elements later).

```
    struct ensRow {
        var adLastName: String = ""
        var adMaidenName: String = ""
        var adFirstName: String = ""
        var adAge: String = ""
        var adLocation: String = ""
        var adDeathDate: String = ""
        var adPubDate: String = ""
        var adPubDate2: String = ""
        var adPubDate3: String = ""
        var adObitDate: String = ""
        var adObitDate2: String = ""
        var adObitDate3: String = ""
        var adSource: String = ""
        var adSection: String = ""
        var adPage: String = ""
        var adPhotoAvailable: String = ""
        var adUDF1: String = ""
        var adUDF2: String = ""
        var adUDF3: String = ""
        var adNotes: String = ""
        var adFrom: String = ""
    }
    var ensArray: [ensRow] = []
```

I need to remove duplicates efficiently either as I fill the array or after it's filled. I thought maybe I could set it up as a set objects if I can make them hashable (not sure how) and if there is a conditional way to add members to the set. However, ideally I would like the last property (adFrom) to be variable while still removing structs with duplicates in all the other properties. Any suggestions for how best to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Related to making your structs hashable: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32953118/2227743

Comment: Great! That works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work - kind of brute force and rather slow, but...

```
struct ensRow:Equatable {
    var adLastName: String = ""
    var adMaidenName: String = ""
    var adFirstName: String = ""
    var adAge: String = ""
    var adLocation: String = ""
    var adDeathDate: String = ""
    var adPubDate: String = ""
    var adPubDate2: String = ""
    var adPubDate3: String = ""
    var adObitDate: String = ""
    var adObitDate2: String = ""
    var adObitDate3: String = ""
    var adSource: String = ""
    var adSection: String = ""
    var adPage: String = ""
    var adPhotoAvailable: String = ""
    var adUDF1: String = ""
    var adUDF2: String = ""
    var adUDF3: String = ""
    var adNotes: String = ""
    var adFrom: String = ""
}

func ==(lhs: ensRow, rhs: ensRow) -> Bool {
    if lhs.adLastName != rhs.adLastName {
        return false
    }
    return lhs.adLastName == rhs.adLastName
        && lhs.adMaidenName == rhs.adMaidenName
        && lhs.adFirstName == rhs.adFirstName
        && lhs.adAge == rhs.adAge
        && lhs.adLocation == rhs.adLocation
        && lhs.adDeathDate == rhs.adDeathDate
        && lhs.adPubDate == rhs.adPubDate
        && lhs.adPubDate2 == rhs.adPubDate2
        && lhs.adPubDate3 == rhs.adPubDate3
        && lhs.adObitDate == rhs.adObitDate
        && lhs.adObitDate2 == rhs.adObitDate2
        && lhs.adObitDate3 == rhs.adObitDate3
        && lhs.adSource == rhs.adSource
        && lhs.adSection == rhs.adSection
        && lhs.adPage == rhs.adPage
        && lhs.adPhotoAvailable == rhs.adPhotoAvailable
        && lhs.adUDF1 == rhs.adUDF1
        && lhs.adUDF2 == rhs.adUDF2
        && lhs.adUDF3 == rhs.adUDF3
        && lhs.adNotes == rhs.adNotes
}
```