# How to find if array contains object

Tags: arrays, swift

I have created a custom class called `MenuItem`:

```
import Foundation

class MenuItem {

    var title: String
    var tag: Int
    var image: UIImage

    init (title: String, tag: Int, image: UIImage) {
        self.title = title
        self.tag = tag
        self.image = image
    }

}
```

I am adding these objects to an array.

How can I check if an array contains a specific menu item?

This is a simplified version of what I have tried.

```
let menuOptionInventory = MenuItem(title: "Inventory", tag: 100, image: UIImage(imageLiteral: "871-handtruck"))
var menuOptions = [MenuItem]()
menuOptions.append(menuOptionInventory)

if (menuOptions.contains(menuOptionInventory)) {
    //does contain object
}
```

When I do this I get this error message:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'MenuItem' to expected argument type '@noescape (MenuItem) throws -> Bool'
```

Comment: You can have a look here for how to conform to equatable and/or hashable: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32953118/2227743

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

```
if menuOptions.contains( { $0 === menuOptionInventory } ) {
    //does contain object
}
```

Edit: As JAL pointed out this does compare pointers.

So instead you could override the `==` operator specifically for a comparison between two `MenuItem` objects like this:

```
func == (lhs: MenuItem, rhs: MenuItem) -> Bool {
    return lhs.title == rhs.title && lhs.tag == rhs.tag && lhs.image == rhs.image
}
```

And then you could use the contain method closure to perform a comparison between the objects.

```
if menuOptions.contains( { $0 == menuOptionInventory } ) {
    //does contain object
}
```

Comment: This will compare pointers, not object equality iirc (I didn't downvote).

Comment: Added an alternate solution, hopefully the downvoter might like it :)

Comment: In my scenario, pointer comparison was fine. I appreciate both answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A few issues:

`contains` takes in a closure.  You would need to do your comparison like this:

```
if menuOptions.contains( { $0 == menuOptionInventory } ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

But now you'll get the issue that `==` cannot be applied to two `MenuItem` objects.  Conform your object to `Hashable` and `Equatable` and define how two `MenuItem` objects are equal, or use a base class that conforms to `Hashable` and `Equatable` for you, such as `NSObject`.