# indexOf using with arrays in Swift

Tags: swift

I have an array:

```
var swiftBlogs:[Message] = [Message]()
```

And I want to find index number of some object. I tried following code:

```
let mm=Message()
swiftBlogs.indexOf(mm)
```

But I am getting compiler error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Message' to expected argument type '@noescape (Message) throws -> Bool'
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: What's `Message`? Is it `Equatable`?

Comment: It is a simple class

Comment: Which version of Swift?

Comment: I dont know the number but xcode is updated to latest version. So It is >2.0

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32953118/2227743

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Message {
    var id: Int
    init(id: Int) {
        self.id = id
    }
}

var arr: [Message] = []
arr.append(Message(id: 1))
arr.append(Message(id: 2))
arr.append(Message(id: 3))
print(arr.indexOf { $0.id == 2 }) // Optional(1)
```

check the declaration !!

> .indexOf(predicate: (Message) throws -> Bool)

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 3 it's:

```
myArray.index{$0 === myMessage}
```

And it returns an Optional.

Comment: elaborate your answer a little more.