# Searching Array of Dictionary Objects in Swift 2

Tags: json, swift, swift2, nsdictionary

I have an array of dictionary objects populated from a JSON file defined as:

```
var peopleArray = [Person]()
```

`Person` is defined as:

```
class Person {

    var name: String?
    var gender: String?
    var html_url: String?

    init(json: NSDictionary) { // Dictionary object
        self.name = json["name"] as? String
        self.gender = json["gender"] as? String
        self.html_url = json["html_url"] as? String // Location of the JSON file
    }
}
```

Once the array has been populated, I am struggling to use the `contains` function to determine whether there is someone with a specific `name`.

I am thrown the following error: `Cannot convert value of type 'String!' to expected argument type '@noescape (Person) throws -> Bool'` for the following line I've attempted:

```
if (peopleArray.contains("Bob"))
```

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32953118/2227743 (your objects should conform to Equatable)

Comment: Slightly off topic, but you might find it easier to use SwiftyJSON. https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Comment: Your predicate can simply be $0.name == "Bob"

Comment: @EricD it's not exactly a duplicate. This could be solved also without making `Person` conform to `Equatable`, just using a closure as the passed value in the `contains` call, like: `{ $0.name == "Bob" }`.

Comment: @AlessandroOrrù You are right. I believe it's better to make it Equatable like in my example, but yes, absolutely, they can do that. I've reopened the question.

Comment: @EricD Thinking about it again, making it conform to Equatable doesn't mean that you are looking for a specific name, but for a specific Person as a whole.

Comment: @AlessandroOrrù Sure. :) However, given this specific question, I thought it was actually better, therefore the linked duplicate. But your answer is actually perfect for OP, it shows both ways - it's better than just my link anyway. +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a closure as input parameter of `contains` call:

```
peopleArray.contains { person -> Bool in
    person.name == "Bob"
}
```

or with the short style syntax:

```
peopleArray.contains { $0.name == "Bob" }
```

Alternatively, if what you want is to look for a specific person, you could make `Person` conform to `Equatable`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32953118/2227743