# Swift 3 Graph: FILTER and CONTAINS for Entities

Tags: ios, xcode, graph, swift3, cosmicmind

here's my problem.

I have a "allPlayers" array Entity.

I have a "players" Relationship between a "team" and a "allPlayers" entities.

I want a list of all players that are not in this team yet.

So:

```
func availablePlayer(_ team:Entity) -> [Entity] {

    let playersTeam = players.filter { $0.subject == team }.flatMap { [$0.object] }

    let playersAvailable = allPlayers.filter { !playersTeam.contains($0) }

    return playersAvailable
}
```

in playersTeam will be stored the allPlayers in players relationship given a team.
Then, I want to filter the allPlayers array that not contains the playersTeam.

but the `!playersTeam.contains($0)` give me an error.
Entity has not "contains" method.
It only has "contains(where:)"

Any idea?

Comment: You want to make your Entity model conform to the needed protocol. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32953118/2227743) I have an example (the question is about indexOf but it's the same issue you have, actually). If you don't like this example there's many others, of course. ;) // *Or* you could use a closure in`contains(where:)`, this also would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to answer your question, I will setup your model the way I understand it. First let's setup our Team Entities:

```
let tA = Entity(type: "Team")
tA["name"] = "A"

let tB = Entity(type: "Team")
tB["name" = "B"
```

and now some Player Entities.

```
let p1 = Entity(type: "Player")
p1["name"] = "Daniel"

let p2 = Entity(type: "Player")
p2["name"] = "Eve"
```

Making a relationship:

```
p1.is(relationship: "TeamMember").of(object: ta)
```

Now we save it all:

```
let graph = Graph()
graph.sync()
```

Now we search for all players:

```
let search = Search<Entity>(graph: graph).for(types: "Player")
let players = search.sync()
```

And now we want all players that are not part of a team, which means they are not part of any relationships with TeamMember Relationship types.

```
let result = players.filter { (player) -> Bool in
    return player.relationship(types: "TeamMember").count == 0
}
```

That should be it. Let me know if I understood correctly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Almost everything perfect.
But I had to return a list of Players they are not in a specific given Team.
(A Player can be part of multiple Team at the same time)

After several attempts, I figured out the way:

```
func availablePlayer(_ team:Entity) -> [Entity] {

    let playersTeam = Set(players.filter { $0.subject == team }.flatMap { [$0.object] })

    let playersAvailable = allPlayers.filter { !playersTeam.contains($0) }

    return playersAvailable
}
```

Converting playersTeam in a Set, I could use "contains" method.